# Is "you lil stubborn" a common phrase/idiom?

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage

To me it sounds like a common phrase/idiom. However, [Google disagrees](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22you%20lil%27%20stubborn%22&rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&oq=%22you%20lil%27%20stubborn%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.4520j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Example sentence:

> Climbing up the tree again? Oh, you lil stubborn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not.

My guess is that it's a fragment from something like, "the stubborn little hellion that you are....". Or it's a fragment of a common saying such as, "why you little stubborn bastard/child/idiot/fiend/brat/etc.".

It's absolutely not a common idiom. In fact, as presented, it's not even a complete sentence. That's why I say it's most likely a sentence fragment and furthermore if there is more to the sentence then it's still probably an idea fragment created from one of those phrases.